# Diagram / graphical view of Hive metadata

Tags: hadoop, hive, hcatalog

I want to obtain a graphical view (a diagram) of the [Hive](https://hive.apache.org) metadata (table definition and properties + mapping on HDFS).

The obvious tool for browsing these information is [Hue](http://gethue.com). There is also alternatives like the one proposed by [Toad](https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-hadoop/w/wiki/11116.product-features), the tool widely used for relational databases.

But these tools -- as far as I know -- do not provide a graphical view. Does someone know a tool, maybe based on [HCatalog](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog), permitting to obtain this view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use data modeling tools such as Microsoft Visio, ERWin. Even tools like Toad, SQL Developer etc provide visualization layer for data models.

But MS Visio, ERWin are better to visualize data models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do MS Visio and ERWin provide a connector to get metadata from Hive and generate a diagram ?

Comment: You need to connect to DB being used for hive metadata. Typically it will be in MySQL or Postgres or Oracle.